# My.Computer.Network.UploadFile

Tags: file-upload, network-programming

What should I use for the "User" parameter of this function? Is this the name of the account that the user logs in with? Computer name?

I am trying to send a file across to another computer on my network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the username to pass for HTTP basic authentication.

If you're uploading to a site that gives a standard *browser* login dialog (not a normal login form), you should pass the username and password to this function.

Most web pages uses forms-based authentication with a normal login form; if so, you'll need to login using cookies and a separate HTTP request.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I really should have mentioned that I want to upload a file to another computer on my network. I keep getting an login failure because of bad password/username. Although I will keep that in mind when I get into that stuff.

Comment: @Skeela: You're calling the wrong function; this uploads to an HTTP server.

Comment: You should either run a server on the target machine or add a network share and do a normal filecopy.

Comment: I could do that. This is more of a theory since I was able to use this function to upload a file to myself, so I was just venturing out. It's just for testing purposes, I don't really need it for anything, so it's fine if a solution can't be come to.